# A smarter inline than ternary for dealing with undefined objects

Tags: javascript, inline

**This is a question asking if such a technique exists..**

I am looking for a way in general to do an inline statement that performs an action if the item object is defined else does nothing (so instead of (condition)?if:else; it is just (condition)?if;)

```
(item)?[item.member='foo']:0;   //ReferenceError: item is not defined

var item={'member':'bar'};//item could be an object but it wasn't defined
```

I would have thought that there was a way beside 'try catch error'

for a hypothetical (somewhat impractical but best that I could think of) example

> In the following snippet there might be lots of code surrounding the lines and many things going on. Is there a neat way to say only draw if the pen is defined as sometimes-but-not-always there is to be drawing done, sometimes no drawing - only the surrounding calculations instead. So the canvas is not always in use

```
//calculations and code
if(drawing===true){
    var pen=document.getElementById('canvas');
    pen=pen.getContext("2d");
    //other canvas setup stuff
    }
//calculations and code
pen.moveTo(0,0);
pen.lineTo(10,10);
```

the last two lines it would be great if there was some trick in JavaScript to do something like (pseudo code):

```
(pen) ? pen.lineTo(10,10);
```

**This would throw unexpected ; error!**

Is there a different kind of inline other than ternary and a way to *return* if the object is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//var pen;   not declared

(!window.pen)&&console.log('no pen');
(window.pen)&&console.log('is pen');
```

this will print 'no pen' and will **not** throw error

```
var pen=document.getElementById('canvas');
    pen=pen.getContext("2d");


(window.pen)&&pen.lineTo(10,10);
```

or if you don't use words reserved in jquery

```
$.pen=$('#canvas')[0];
  pen=pen.getContext("2d");

($.pen)&&pen.lineTo(10,10);
```

Do a bunch of things in order:

```
($.pen)&&[
    pen.lineTo(10,10),
    pen.lineTo(20,20),
    pen.lineTo(30,30)];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two that I know of:

```
// Set a variable if not set
var x = x || 'hi';

// Do something if x is truthy
// Needs a scope, may not always be "this."
this.x && console.log(this.x);
```

So in your example, if `pen` is global, you can do `window.pen && pen.lineTo(10, 10);`

There's also the very simple one-line if:

```
if (pen) pen.lineTo(10, 10);
```

which technically isn't shorthand of any kind, it's just short. Compare the two line lengths (your pseudo-code versus this method):

```
(pen) ? pen.lineTo(10,10);
if (pen) pen.lineTo(10, 10);
```

---

Getting a bit more in-depth, I'd recommend against something like

```
if (pen) pen.moveTo(0, 0);
if (pen) pen.lineTo(10, 10);
```

because yes it's a couple of one-liners but you're doubling up logic, repeating yourself and you'll make people think "**why** did he do that?". In that situation, I'd just keep it simple:

```
if (pen) {
    pen.moveTo(0, 0);
    pen.lineTo(10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have expanded on both your answers +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, hoewever, you need to declare the variable somehow, e.g.:

```
// declare pen
var pen;
//calculations and code
if(drawing===true){
    pen=document.getElementById('canvas');
    pen=pen.getContext("2d");
    //other canvas setup stuff
    }
//calculations and code
pen && pen.moveTo(0,0);
pen && pen.lineTo(10,10);
```

Comment: Thanks I have expanded on both your answers +1